# data context passed limit Plugin CRM

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working on a plugin which is fired on the creation of the "Notes" annotation entity. But when attached file which is more then 10 MB size then plugin not execute.
what I want to know is what is the maximum limit of the data which is passed to the plugin. ?
plugin is working fine if I attached document which is less then 10 MB and is is not working if file size is more then 10 MB.
I have also used Async execution of the plugin so that I can check the error in system job but there is no error , system job is marked as "In Progress"
there is no detail about any error.
any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

did you check if the note actually has the file attached?  CRM has a configurable limit for attachment size - which defaults to 5MB, so you are probably getting blocked there unless you have increased that limit.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a bit more to what @Joseph said.

Here is the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kennethw/2011/08/19/how-to-increase-crm-2011-attachment-file-size-from-5mb-to-maximum-32mb/) which explains how to setup the file size limit for attachments.

CRM must be checking the file size limit before giving a chance to your plugin to be executed.